# Replicate Excel's mode function using SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2005, mode

How can I replicate *Excel's* mode function using *SQL*?

If I run the mode function on a set of numbers in Excel it will return one mode value even if there are multiple mode values.  I need some *SQL* to work in the same way.

For this series of numbers Excel returns a mode of 8.  This is probably because 8 is the first modal number to appear.

```
6
7
8
3
3
8
0
2
2
```

If there is no mode example all numbers are unique it should return NA.

This is the code I have so far.

How can I replicate *Excel's* mode function using *SQL*?
If I run the mode function on a set of numbers in Excel it will return one mode value even if there are multiple mode values.  I need some *SQL* to work in the same way.

This is what I have so far.  deleting rows where `occurences=1` is to deal with series with no mode.

```
 --I wanted to use CTE for Mode, but it won't work as part of a union query
select RIC,Period,InputFile,Occurrences,amount into #Mode1 from
(SELECT aa.RIC,aa.Period,aa.inputfile,aa.amount,COUNT(*) AS occurrences
FROM tempPivotTable aa
--where aa.ric='USTRDAP' and aa.period='2006' and aa.inputfile='C:\FalconIngest\Input\US April 2006.xls'
GROUP BY aa.RIC,aa.Period,aa.inputfile,aa.amount) as A

Select RIC,vendor,Period,Filedate,inputfile,YearlyOrQuarterly,sortablePeriod,NumericFiledate,MaxAmount into #Mode2 from
(
select t.Ric,'O' as vendor,t.Period,Filedate,t.inputfile,YearlyOrQuarterly,sortablePeriod,NumericFiledate,max(occurrences) as MaxAmount
from TempPivotTable t
inner join #Mode1 A
on t.ric=a.ric and t.period=a.period and t.inputfile=a.inputfile
group by t.Ric,t.Period,Filedate,t.inputfile,YearlyOrQuarterly,sortablePeriod,NumericFiledate
)as A

Select RIC,vendor,Period,Filedate,inputfile,YearlyOrQuarterly,sortablePeriod,NumericFiledate,Amount,occurrences into #Mode3 from
(
select a.RIC, 'O' as vendor,a.period,Filedate,a.inputfile,YearlyOrQuarterly,sortablePeriod,NumericFiledate,Amount,occurrences
from #Mode1 A
inner join #Mode2 M
on A.ric=M.ric and A.period=M.period and A.inputfile=M.Inputfile
where occurrences=maxamount 
) as A

--deal with cases where there is no mode
select ric,vendor,period,Filedate,inputfile,YearlyOrQuarterly,sortablePeriod,NumericFiledate,Amount
into #mode4 
from(
select   ric,'O' as vendor,period,Filedate,inputfile,YearlyOrQuarterly,sortablePeriod,NumericFiledate,0 as Amount from #mode3
where occurrences=1 
group by ric,period,Filedate,inputfile,YearlyOrQuarterly,sortablePeriod,NumericFiledate
having count(*)>1
) as A
delete from #mode3 where occurrences=1 

select a.RIC, 'O' as vendor,a.period,Filedate,a.inputfile,YearlyOrQuarterly,sortablePeriod,NumericFiledate,Amount
from #Mode1 A
inner join #Mode2 M
on A.ric=M.ric and A.period=M.period and A.inputfile=M.Inputfile
where occurrences=maxamount and maxamount>1
union select * from #mode4  --Put series with no mode as NA

drop table #mode1
drop table #mode2
drop table #mode3
drop table #mode4
```

subsquently,
I've come up with this simplified code.

```
select Code,inputfile,period,Amount,count(*) as Amountcount,
Ranking=dense_Rank() over (partition by Code,period,inputfile order by count(*) desc)
from TempPivotTable
group by Code,inputfile,period,Amountmore of those amount is the modal amount.
```

It's OK where there is one mode value.  In the example below 3 and 8 are the mode values.  Where there are multiple mode values it must choose 8 as that appears first in the alphabetical list of vendors.

Vendor Amount
A           6
B           7
C           8
D           3
E           3
F           8
G           0
H           2
I            2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below statement return mode value if it is single, mode value of the first (alphabetically) Vendor if set is multimodal, and return NULL if all values unique (no mode exist).

```
;with m as (
    select *,
        aCnt = count(1) over (partition by amount),
        tCnt = count(1) over ()
    from TableName
)
select top (1)
    case
        when acnt = 1 and tCnt > 1 then NULL
        else amount
    end as mode
from m
order by acnt desc, vendor;
```

[**SQLFiddle sample**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d695/115)

To find mode within `(inputfile, code, period)` tuple you may try:

```
;with r1 as (
    select inputfile, code, period, vendor, amount,
        acnt = count(1) over (partition by inputfile, code, period, amount),
        tcnt = count(1) over (partition by inputfile, code, period)
    from TableName
),
r2 as (
    select inputfile, code, period, amount, acnt, tcnt,
        rn = row_number() over (partition by inputfile, code, period order by acnt desc, vendor)
    from r1
)
select inputfile, code, period,
    mode = case when acnt = 1 and tcnt > 1 then NULL else amount end
from r2
where rn = 1
```

[**SQLFiddle sample**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d695/116)

Comment: I need a mode per combination of inputfile, code and period.  Each input file has lots of codes.  Each code has lots of periods.  Each period has its own rows, so an inputfile can 50 rows for example.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the delay.  I've just amended my preferences to have email notifications sent to me